# value callback not called when startAt used

Tags: node.js, callback, firebase

When I add a startAt(priority) to an on("value", fn) call I don't get callbacks after the node is created.

```
var myDataRef = firebaseRef.push(data);  
myDataref.startAt(200).on("value", fn(snap) { blah });
```

My setup:

- I have a client that pushes data to Firebase.
- The client adds a value callback on the data ref returned in the step above.
- I have a server component that use uses the firebase-work-queue to extract items from Firebase as they arrive. But instead of removing the items from the queue, I set the priority of the item to 100 to mark it as claimed by a worker.
- The server component then does its thing with the data and when finished, updates the data and sets the priority to 200. Marking the task as complete.

On the client, if I DON'T USE startAt(200), I get the following callbacks:

1. A null value when the data is first pushed.
2. Then I get a callback with the data that I actually pushed.
3. Finally, I get a callback when the data is updated and priority 200 is set.

You'll notice that I didn't get a callback when the server claimed the queue entry and set the priority to 100. I've noticed that just changing a node's priority doesn't generate value callbacks. I guess that's technically correct since you're not changing the value, just the priority. And technically correct is the best kind of correct.

I've structure my code to ignore the extraneous callback in step 1 & 2 above. But I'd like to use startAt(200) to prevent those callbacks. However when I apply startAt(200), I only get the first callback with null data (step 1). This doesn't make sense as it doesn't even have a priority.

So my question is what is going on here?

Comment: Any reason you're stuck using priorities (intended for sorting) to store meta data about records? I use queues quite frequently and I tend to store the record keys in indices called claimed/ and unclaimed/. This works nicely with onDisconnect() (should the server go offline) by depositing the keys back in the unclaimed/ pile and simplifies the transactions necessary.

Comment: This is my first experience with Firebase and when I found that I could filter with the priorities, I thought it might be a good mechanism. I've since run into other requirements that are forcing me to change my approach to be more like what you suggested. However, I still don't understand the behavior I'm seeing with the way I'm using the priorities.